# cURL POST data to Service Stack not being deserialized into Request object

Tags: web-services, rest, curl, servicestack

I am using Service Stack to host some REST web services. I can call the web services with soapUI and the data is sent and deserialized to my request object correctly. However, when I try to use cURL, the request object is completely empty.

I have looked through the service stack code and I think the issue is somewhere around RestHandler.cs, when it gets the request parameters and creates the request object. There doesn't seem to be anything in the request that it can deserialize.

My request object is as follows:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.WsdlServiceTypesNamespace)]
public class Request
{
    [DataMember]
    public Parameter[] Parameters { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

and the cURL that I am using is:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d "Parameters":[{"Name":"data","Value":""}],"Name":"Test" http://localhost:8084/test
```

I have tried various permutations of content type and data with the same result. Can anyone suggest any reason why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out the content type was incorrect and should be text/json, along with a charset. Also, escaping the json may have helped.

So, the cURL becomes:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: text/json; charset=UTF-8" -X POST -d "{\"Parameters\":[{\"Name\":\"data\",\"Value\":\"test\"}],\"Name\":\"Test\"}" http://localhost:8084/test
```